# Download files via curl using python's subprocess

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

How is it that when I write this in my terminal the file is downloaded,

```
curl "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p50.pl?file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2016121900" -o "tmp_folder/gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000"
```

but using python's subprocess module, the download just hangs?

```
import subprocess
```

URL = "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p50.pl?file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2016121900"

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("curl " + URL + " -o" + " my_file", shell = True)
pipe.communicate()
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: why are you calling communicate?  and you should use subprocess.call() instead of creating a Popen instance.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is probably not properly quoted, so it is interpreted by the shell (with all the `&` chars...)

Better run subprocess with explicit arguments as a `list`:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["curl",URL,"-o","my_file"])
```

`shell=True` can probably be omitted. Since you're not using any shell capabilities, it will save you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

rather than creating a `Popen` instance, you can just use the `call` method.  Don't pass `shell=True`... just split the command with `shlex` so the args can be passed as a list.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = 'curl "http://foo.com" -o "foo.txt"'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```